# How do commands fill up the screen?

Tags: command-line, echo

Some commands, like curl if you do the -# option, fill up the entire screen, even if you resize. How is this done?

Answer (score 0):

They probably make use of the `LINES` and `COLUMNS` environment variables. See `man resize`.

Comment: But how exactly?

Comment: SMOP - Simple Matter Of Programming - treat the screen as a 2D array `LINES`x`COLUMNS`